# What is a collection expression when instantiating a List<T>

Tags: c#, list, destructuring, enumerable, c#-12.0

I don't understand what Intellisense is suggesting as a replacement for my existing code (pictured here)
[image]

In case the image gets deleted later, the Intellisense suggestion that is pictured suggests replacing

```
List<int> x = new List<int>();
x.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(0, 300));
```

with

```
List<int> x = [.. Enumerable.Range(0, 300)];
```

I assume that `..` is the Range Operator that was introduced in C# 8.0, but there is no documentation surrounding this suggested usage.

- Is there an implicit 'new List' when the Range Operator is used this way?
- I understand that the left-hand-side of the .. operator can be blank (implied zero), but I don't understand how the enumerable range can be used as the right-hand-side of the .. operator.

If someone could explain what's happening "under the hood" of this specific usage of [x..y] in regards to instantiating a new List, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: The `new` is implied by the `[` construct.  The `..` is just saying "if you have other elements in the list, put them here".  You should be able to delete the `..`

Comment: If I do that, then I get error CS0029 (can't convert System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<int> to 'int') and CS8619 (nullability of reference types in value of type ienumerable doesn't match type int)

Comment: You can try it by yourself: https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghglgdgNAExAagD4AEBMBGAsAKHQAYACdbAFgG4DizsA6AGVgEcb9aBmMzEgYRIBvAiTFke6CiQCyACgCUw0eNUsAzgBcAPLE0A+EgA8SAXhIwApgHcSGnXv2KOq1UYYBBBAgBKEGADmlnIAojAArmCWAE4QwAA2lgx+gcFEcCRcREQKCi7iAL4qYsUSZNIAcorK+K7i9rowBsZmJADaDAwkYZExcYnJ/kFy6ZnZCgC6+WJF+AVAA==

Comment: That sharplab thing is cool. I'll use that in the future. Thanks.

Comment: Took me a while to find it, but this is the new [collection expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-12#collection-expressions) of C# 12, which was released yesterday with .NET 8.

Comment: I personally would prefer to use `Enumerable.Range(0, 300).ToList();` as it is more expressive, but I might also get used to collection expressions.

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the info @JeanotZubler!
I think one of the benefits of the new way is that you can append to it `List<int> x = [..Enumerable.Range(0, 300),2,2,2,2];` for example.

Comment: On the other hand with the old way you can additionally preallocate the list with `new List<int>(300);`. Honestly, I find this feature useless. Maybe even harmful, since it can lead to unreadable one-liners.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Jeanot Zubler commented: this is the new [collection expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-12#collection-expressions) of C# 12, which was released yesterday with .NET 8.

It allows for example this syntax:

```
int[] row0 = [1, 2, 3];
int[] row1 = [4, 5, 6];
int[] row2 = [7, 8, 9];
int[] single = [..row0, ..row1, ..row2];
```

or in your case this:

```
List<int> x = [.. Enumerable.Range(0, 300)];
```

The `..` is a kind of "flatten"-operator if i understood it correctly (officially: "spread operator").